# .checked option not working on my javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showdiv">SHOW ME!

<div id="hello" style="display:none">
  Hello world!
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("showdiv").checked ? document.getElementById("hello").style.display = "inline" : document.getElementById("hello").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

where is the error?
The div won't display on click...

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Comment: are you trying to check the checkbox or trying to set the display property

Comment: show the hidden div if the checkbox is checked

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your script to the onclick function of the checkbox.

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("showdiv").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("showdiv").checked ? document.getElementById("hello").style.display = "inline" : '';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is the code that is adding the click event? The browser does not understnd that is supposed to run onclick

```
(function() {
    var cb = document.getElementById("showdiv");
    cb.onclick = function() {  //would be better to add it with addEventListener
        document.getElementById("hello").style.display = cb.checked ? "block" : 'none';
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an [event-listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) to the element, that trigger your code when the checkbox is clicked. As it is now, your code is executed immediately, and at that point the checkbox isn't checked.

```
document.getElementById("showdiv").addEventListener("click", callback, false);

function callback() {
    if (document.getElementById("showdiv").checked)
       document.getElementById("hello").style.display = "inline";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjrcg/)

*Notice that `addEventListener` wasn't supported by IE prior to IE9, so for legacy browsers you need a work around for attaching the event-listener. (Described in above referenced article)*

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
document.getElementById("showdiv").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("hello").style.display = this.checked ? 'inline' : 'none'
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E5rwK/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Tested with Fiddler

```
document.getElementById("showdiv").addEventListener("click", callback, false);

function callback() {
document.getElementById("showdiv").checked ? document.getElementById("hello").style.display = "inline" : document.getElementById("hello").style.display = "none";
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjrcg/1/)